# What is the symmetry group of a sum of n square doublets? $X= (a+b)^2+(c+d)^2+(e+f)^2...$

Tags: lie-groups, symmetry

Clear the symmetry group of $a^2+b^2+...=C$, where $C$ is a constant, are the circle and its higher-dimensional versions.

But what is the symmetry group given by

$$
(a+b)^2+(c+d)^2=C
$$

and

$$
(a+b)^2+(c+d)^2+(e+f)^2=C
$$

and finally, in the n case

$$
(a+b)^2+(c+d)^2+(e+f)^2+...=C
$$

Comment: Just rotate the coordinates $45^\circ$: $$x_1=\frac{a+b}{\sqrt2},\;y_1=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt2}\\ x_2=\frac{c+d}{\sqrt2},\;y_2=\frac{c-d}{\sqrt2}\\ x_3=\frac{e+f}{\sqrt2},\;y_3=\frac{e-f}{\sqrt2}$$ So your quadratic form becomes $$2x_1\!^2+2x_2\!^2+2x_3\!^2+0y_1\!^2+0y_2\!^2+0y_3\!^2$$

Comment: @mr_e_man Neat! so the same as a circle then...?

Comment: A cylinder, so to say.

Comment: Not quite... $x^2+0y^2=C$ is a pair of parallel lines in the plane. This type of quadratic form is degenerate.

Comment: @mr_e_man I do not understand the role of $0y^2$. Since it's multiplied by $0$ can it not just be ignored?

Comment: I write out the $0$'s only to emphasize that there are more variables. $x^2=C$ could be misinterpreted as a pair of points in $1$ dimension, instead of a pair of parallel lines in $2$ dimensions. Likewise, $2x_1\!^2+2x_2\!^2+2x_3\!^2=C$ could be misinterpreted as a sphere in $3$ dimensions, instead of a hyper-cylinder in $6$ dimensions.